# Create my own timeline by collating data from different research

Tags: geomorphology, paleoclimate

I'm researching various paleo-events (climate, geomorphology, etc) from different articles. I would in turn like to collate the findings into one comprehensive timeline.

Example:
I have articles dealing with specific events happening in specific years (ex. 7989 B.P.), seasons in years (ex. winter 7989 B.P.), and year ranges (ex. 8100 - 7800 B.P.). The events are (a) changes in SST, SSS, precipitation, humidity, RSL; or (b) changes in geomorphology as a result of SL change or tectonics. The events also happen (1) locally, (2) regionally, or (3) globally (ex, the local pollen record changes due to changes in regional paleoclimate, which in turn are interconnected to global paleoclimatic changes.)

So various articles discuss the local, regional, and global changes using the different proxies. And I would like to create my own timeline and keep track of all these changes.
And I would like this timeline to include year ranges, specific years, and seasons within a year. Coupled to this, I want to be able to see what is happening in the proxy record, the paleoenvironment, and the citation of my sources. In essence, it's a database.

But I'm not familiar with creating my own database. Excel is getting too convoluted. I've resorted to putting sticky notes on my window and shuffling them around as I add new events.

Is there a program for this? (I'm familiar with Tilia and PAST, but those require raw data...and I just want to collate the different papers).

Thank you and apologies for such long text.

Comment: Unfortunately people tend to use spreadsheets to establish databases when spreadsheets were never meant to be databases. Which database system to use depends on how complex or simple the database needs to be. Building somethings from scratch using either Microsoft Access or LibreOffice Base might be an option.

Comment: Yes, I realize spreadsheets are not the way to go. And I have a basic understanding of building my own database, so I'm reluctant to start now as I'm in the middle of research. I was hoping there was software out there already. Or a database template I could use.